# Two questions closed. Why?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I got two of my questions closed one after the other:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56101/unity-problems-searching-for-a-good-wm
- [Would you say FreeBSD is more stable than Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56103/would-you-say-freebsd-is-more-stable-than-linux)

One of those was even voted and answered with interesting feedback. Sure, it wasn't a typical very specific question but rather a broad subject. But do all of them have to be that way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both these questions are to some extent “[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)”. Even though you're not buying anything for money, you're asking us which item you should pick.

This kind of question often degenerates into “what's your favorite …”. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56101/unity-problems-searching-for-a-good-wm is a clear case: you're asking us to tell you which window manager to use. There are hundreds of window managers out there, many of which are very unlikely to crash. With such broad requirements, you might as well head up to some window manager list on Wikipedia or in your distribution's package list or some other application list.

[Would you say FreeBSD is more stable than Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56103/would-you-say-freebsd-is-more-stable-than-linux) is more focused as it pitches Linux against FreeBSD. It happens to be misguided — you're actually not opposing kernels but window managers. The question needs to be unasked, and the [answer you've accepted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56103/would-you-say-freebsd-is-more-stable-than-linux/56116#56116) does this adequately. I think this question is reasonable and I've voted to reopen it.

Both these questions have quite a bit of an underlying rant — Linux/Unity sucks. I recommend avoiding this. You are a lot less likely to get help about something if you disparage it in your question. This same tone tends to tip the balance towarsd a downvote or a close vote even among readers who don't particularly care about your target.

Answer (score 6):

It's not that your questions are poor in the absolute sense. They just don't fit the *specific mission of this Q&A site*.

Both of those questions have closed-message notices referring you to [the site faq](https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#close), which really should cover what you're asking here. Read that section and [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask). If it's still not clear, feel free to follow up here or in chat.

If you'd like to have a more open-ended discussion, check out [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You're fostering binary ppl, chat===blablabla / forum===original research